# REGEXP_REPLACE - two letters in a string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regex-replace

I have a string:

```
string := '</br>, <br/>, \n<br>, jane, brutus'
```

I have to replace all 'br' marks by '/n' mark. I need an output like this:

```
'/n, /n, n/, jane, brutus'
```

I tried:

```
select regexp_replace('</br>, <br/>, \n<br>, ania', '^.*((br)[^,]+)', '\n', 1) from dual;
```

But then output is like this:

```
'/n'
```

Any ideas how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I mean I tried: 
select regexp_replace('</br>, <br/>, \n<br>, ania, brutus', '^.*((br)[^,]+)', '\n', 1) from dual;

Answer (score 0):

It is easier than you thought. Just look for the 'br> parts. This is: an opening angle bracket, an optional slash, the letters b and r, an optional slash, a closing angle bracket: `</?br/?>`.

The whole expression:

```
select regexp_replace('</br>, <br/>, \n<br>, ania', '</?br/?>', '\n') from dual;
```

If you want to replace all groups of adjacent marks and treat br marks the same as \n in your search, then it gets a little bit more complicated:

```
regexp_replace('</br>, <br/>, \n<br>, ania', '(\\n|</?br/?>)+', '\n')
```

Comment: It doesn't work with '\n<br>'. Output is:
\n, \n, \n\n, ania

Comment: I replace all br marks with \n. What exactly do you want differently?

Comment: I mean '\n<br>' is also one mark with 'br'. I need output like '\n' but with your query output is '\n\n' for this one mark

Comment: Can we generalize: replace any group of br/n marks wth one \n? I.e. '<br>\n<br>hello\n\n<br><br>' would become '\nhello\n'?

Comment: I need '\n' mark instead of every comma separated 'br' mark

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Maybe we mean the same thing. I have updated my query with the generalized "replace any group of br/n marks with one \n".

Comment: @JvdV: Thank you. You are right of course. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this code will be work.

```
SQL>
SELECT word,
   REGEXP_REPLACE (REGEXP_REPLACE (word, '([\\<])([a-zA-Z/]+) 
                    ([>])', '/n'),
                   '\\n([a-zA-Z/]+)',
                   '\1')
      AS Result
   FROM (SELECT '</br>, <br/>, \n<br>, jane, brutus' AS word FROM DUAL)
```

### RESULT

/n, /n, /n, jane, brutus

SQL>